# is there any advanced stock charting library with annotations and drawing tools out there?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, charts

I am working on ruby on rails. I need an extremely advanced stock charting library which includes annotations, drawing tools and indicators in live chart, like the image below:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check http://www.highcharts.com/, but I doubt that you can find exacly what are you looking for.

Comment: What charts did you manage to use? I am also in the same scenario.

Comment: @BrendanVogt, I have not found any?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at :
[fusioncharts.com](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)
and https://developers.google.com/chart/